# UnsatisfiableError while installing open3d with conda

Tags: python, conda, open3d

I'm trying to install [open3d](https://anaconda.org/open3d-admin/open3d) into my conda environment. This is what I did:

```
conda create --name env python=3.9 -y
conda activate env
conda install -c open3d-admin open3d
```

But the last command fails with this output:

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: / 
Found conflicts! Looking for incompatible packages.
This can take several minutes.  Press CTRL-C to abort.
failed                                                                                                      

UnsatisfiableError: The following specifications were found to be incompatible with each other:

Output in format: Requested package -> Available versionsThe following specifications were found to be incompatible with your system:

  - feature:/linux-64::__glibc==2.35=0
  - python=3.9 -> libgcc-ng[version='>=7.5.0'] -> __glibc[version='>=2.17']

Your installed version is: 2.35
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Works with Conda Forge

Not documented, but seems like their packages are built with the `conda-forge` channel prioritized. So, instead try:

```bash
conda create -n env -c conda-forge -c open3d-admin python=3.9 open3d
```

or use YAML:

**so-open3d.yaml**

```yaml
name: so-open3d
channels:
  - conda-forge
  - open3d-admin
  - nodefaults
dependencies:
  - python=3.9
  - open3d
```

with

```bash
conda env create -n env -f so-open3d.yaml
```

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem. I followed merv's answer, and it worked. At least, until I imported open3d in Python, then I receive this error: "[Warning] Since Open3D 0.15, installing Open3D via conda is deprecated. Please re-install Open3D via: `pip install open3d -U`."

It seems Open3D is not supposed to install with conda.